# Fetch BizForm's record in kentico

Tags: content-management-system, repeater, kentico

In kentico How can I fetch Biz forms data in repeater. I am able to save the record using Bizform in my website but I am not able to find any references to fetch the data?

Answer (score 2):

You can use some variant of query repeater. Most ordinary one is "Repeater with custom query".

As "Query name" specify:

> bizform.yourformcodename.selectall

Obviously, change the codename in the query name to yours bizform codename.

And then just create a transformation according your need.